# Are all 9 speed chains compatible with all 9 speed systems?

Tags: chain, frugal

My current chain is x9, but it's expensive in eBay. Can I use any 9 speed chain like on this [page](http://global.ebay.com/search?PageNumber=1&Query=shimano+9+speed+chain&SortBy=21)?

Comment: I edited the title to be clearer; please roll back my edit if it's incorrect.

Comment: @Neil Fein: thank you, it is clearer now. Sorry about the semantic mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK any 9speed chain made for dérailleur should fit (single speed and hub gear chains are different)

9 speed chains are more expensive, they are thinner and not as common - so fewer cheap brands bother to make them, or stores to stock them

BUT - the chain is an important part of the bike, a poor quality chain will stick, jump and wear the rear cassette teeth more quickly. You might not want to buy the very cheapest brand you can find.

Comment: 9 speed is fast becoming the standard, so I think you'll find the 9 (and even 10) speed chains are becoming more and more common and easy to find.

Comment: I asked my local LBS and he said that all 9-speed chains are compatible with 9-speed system, so less room for speculation from AFAIK. He was though hesitant about length because some of his chains were 110, 114 and 118. Any idea about the length? But the answer to the question in the title is `yes`, not taking length into account.

Comment: Never bought chains on length - you just cut them off to the length of the old chain (or http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/setting-chain-length) you might need an extra length for a special setup buti don't know what. Try counting the links on your current chain