# What methods to determine chain length?

Tags: chain

I would like to know what methods there are to size chain length on a derailleur geared bike. There should be more than one answer, so there are effectively no wrong answers - don’t be shy.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of, and *reasons* for, your preferred method?

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was more than one method. Most drivetrain manufacturers suggest the same protocol (see Argenti Apparatus’ answer).

Comment: If you are replacing an existing chain that served you well, you can cut the new chain to be the same length as the old.  But you have to account for *stretch*, so you need to figure the length in *links* rather than inches/cm.  What I do is lay the old and new out on a table and get them lined up link-for-link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting chain length](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/setting-chain-length)

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? There are all kinds of possible dimensions. Also "There are effectively no wrong answers" is a discussion, not a Q&A.

Comment: I'm not voting to close because OP is asking why chains are the length they are as well as how to arrive at that length.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus The question just says "size". The width of the chain is also a kind of size and does vary from chain to chain. But if the question is how to choose the length, isn't it an exact duplicate of the question suggested?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I made an edit to disambiguate 'size'. OP is clear they want to know *why* a chain length determination method works.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus ok. But this is still a duplicate. The answer to the other question is bad because it doesn’t explain why it’s correct, but that doesn’t mean we need a separate question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby y'know what, I'll do I should have done in the first place - add an answer to the dupe and vote to close this.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question. The linked one is about road bikes. This one is more open to someone writing an answer that gets into differences in approach between road and mountain and some other use case considerations.

Comment: Some resources are now suggesting that 2 links be added to 1x systems. Does anyone know why? See for example "With modern, more and more popular systems that have one chainring in the front and multiple chainrings in the back (“1x” systems), the optimal length is achieved when adding two extra links, instead of just one, after wrapping the chain around the only front chainring and the largest rear sprocket" from https://bike.bikegremlin.com/614/chain-length-sizing-for-bicycles-with-derailleurs/

Comment: @BetterSense yeah the old method doesn't necessarily work on 1x with large sprockets at the rear. I recently fitted a Shimano mech that needed 5 links added and it didn't work with less when I initially tried without reading the instructions. This was a badly worded question for the site on my part but I don't think one method of chain sizing suits all bikes anymore either

Answer (score 4):

Starting from a new split chain:

Thread chain onto largest chain ring and largest cassette sprocket. Either thread through front derailleur or move it out of the way. Do not thread chain through rear derailleur.

On the chainring, find the links that will join to form the shortest possible chain that can be connected. Add 1 inch of chain to that (two rivets or 1 inner and 1 outer plate link).

If using a quick-link, remember that takes the place of one outer plate link.

Reading between the lines, what you are actually asking is 'what's the correct length of chain for a modern derailleur' bike?'

Given that modern derailleurs can accommodate the chain running from the chainring to sprockets in almost a straight line, the shortest possible chain that fits over the largest chainring and sprocket, that can run through the derailleur is desired. This is because:

- Eliminates rick of breaking chain or derailleur if largest ring and sprocket are selected.
- Maximizes chain tension and the slack that the derailleur can take up, enabling the largest spread of gear ratios.

If one had a system where the derailleurs could be prevented from selecting the largest chainring and *n* largest cassette sprockets at the same time - which could be programmed into Di2 or eTap systems - then the chain could be sized for the large chainring and *n-1*<sup>th</sup> sprocket.

Comment: That’s great, one on the board. But I want to know the reasons _why_ it’s a good method

Comment: @Swifty see edit

Comment: @Swifty because anything shorter risks ripping off the derailleur and damaging the wheel when big-big cross-chaining. Anything longer and you can get a loose chain and chain slap on small-small combos.